# How can I set IndentationLevel in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift.

How can I set IndentationLevel in `UITableViewCell`?

I have already achieved through Objective C, but I am not able to achieve through Swift.

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
     }

     cell.textLabel.text=[[self.menuTableAr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
     [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.menuTableAr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];

     return cell;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your objective-c code.

Comment: Also, why not in swift, how did you try and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that `valueForKey` will return a `NSNumber` Object

Try

```
let level = self.menuTableAr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("level") as! NSNumber
cell.indentationLevel = Int(level.intValue)
```

Comment: thanks. It's shows me error at exclamation mark "Expected type after "as"". Once I remove exclamation mark, it's work what I wanted.